# @AppStorage in Structs

Tags: swift, swiftui, appstorage

I am really stuck on this. I want to make several button, each having independet state of ifButtonDisabled. The button disables when user clicks on it. Since, I want my app to remember the state of the button when the app reloads or refresh, I am using AppStorage. The problem is since each button has independent state, AppStorage variable should also be different. But since self is not avaialble, I am not able to have a dnamic name for my AppStorage variable.

Also, Is there any better alternative to achieve the same functionality???

```
struct ButtonData {
    var id: UUID {
        return UUID()
    }
    let level: String
    let bgColor: String
    let image: String
    @AppStorage(level) var ifDisabled: Bool = false
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you would want to have an `id` that changes every time you access it, but if you just want to initialise `isDisabled`, you can write your own `init`, and assign an `AppStorage` to `_isDisabled` there.

```
struct ButtonData {
    let level: String
    let bgColor: String
    let image: String

    // note that nothing is passed to @AppStorage here
    // and this property is not initialised to anything - we'll do that in init
    @AppStorage var isDisabled: Bool
    
    init(level: String, bgColor: String, image: String) {
        self.level = level
        self.bgColor = bgColor
        self.image = image
        // this is where isDisabled is initialised to false,
        // and the AppStorage with the level as key is created.
        self._isDisabled = AppStorage(wrappedValue: false, level)
    }
}
```

That said, your view won't update if you want to use it like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var buttonData = ButtonData(level: "foo", bgColor: "bar", image: "baz")
    var body: some View {
        Text("Foo")
            .onTapGesture {
//                buttonData.isDisabled.toggle()
            }
        Button("Button") { ... }.disabled(buttonData.isDisabled)
    }
}
```

Because `AppStorage` has a `nonmutating` setter, so setting it won't cause `buttonData` in the view to mutate, and so SwiftUI doesn't know that your view needs updating.

So if you want `AppStorage` to update views, you need to put it directly in a `View`. For example, you could make your own button view that takes in a `ButtonData`, and sets its disabled status accordingly:

```
// ButtonData can simply be
struct ButtonData {
    let level: String
    let bgColor: String
    let image: String
}

struct MyButton: View {
    let data: ButtonData
    @AppStorage var isDisabled: Bool
    init(data: ButtonData) {
        self.data = data
        self._isDisabled = AppStorage(wrappedValue: false, data.level)
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        // perhaps also provide init parameters for the action...
        Button {
            ...
        } label: {
            Image(data.image)
        }
        .disabled(isDisabled)
    }
}
```

Now whenever the superview updates the `AppStorage`, `MyButton` will update its disabled status too.

Comment: Thank You So Much for such a detailed explanation. It worked.